# Horizontal div tree

Tags: html, css, tree

I want to generate a horizontal tree out of nested divs using css without javascript. The child elements should be in the same depth. Therefore, i created a nested div structure with float left and clear elements. But the child elements aren't in the same depth:

**Please see my JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/bpb680L9/

Is it possible, to position the child element relative to the left side of the parent, not to the text element within the parent? Or to adjust the high of the text to the parent, so that the following child elements are adjusted to the end of the text element? Or is there any other elegant solution to build a horizontal tree with variable number of child elements and siblings only with css and html?

**CSS**

```
div.layout {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
}
div.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    content
    <div class="layout">
        content
        <div class="layout">
            content
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="layout">
            content
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="layout">
        content
        <div class="layout">
            content
            <div class="layout">
                content
                    <div class="layout">
                        content
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out this JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/bpb680L9/2/

```
<div id="wrapper"><span class="label">Root</span>
  <div class="branch lv1">
<div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1</span>
  <div class="branch lv2">
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-1</span>
      <div class="branch lv3">
        <div class="entry sole"><span class="label">Entry-1-1-1</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-2</span>
      <div class="branch lv3">
        <div class="entry sole"><span class="label">Entry-1-2-1</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-3</span>
      <div class="branch lv3">
        <div class="entry sole"><span class="label">Entry-1-3-1</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-2</span></div>
<div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3</span>
  <div class="branch lv2">
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-1</span></div>
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-2</span></div>
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3</span>
      <div class="branch lv3">
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3-1</span></div>
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3-2</span>
          <div class="branch lv4">
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3-2-1</span></div>
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3-2-2</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3-3</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-4</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-4</span></div>
<div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-5</span></div>
```

I've used divs, but the CSS is much more complicated to trully support horizontal tree

Comment: Thank you! This solutions helps me, but it is not optimal to need specifier like sole and branch, because therefore i need to check the number of child-elements and siblings. The classes lv* aren't necessary, are they?

Comment: no, you can do it without the level, using cascaded padding

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML: I wrapped your 'content' with an extra div-tag.

And in your css: i changed left to padding left.

Is this the result you wanted?

HTML:

```
<div>
 <div>content</div>
<div class="layout">
    <div>content</div>
    <div class="layout">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="layout">
        <div>content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="layout">
    <div>content</div>
    <div class="layout">
        <div>content</div>
        <div class="layout">
            <div>content</div>
                <div class="layout">
                    <div>content</div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div.layout {
border: 1px solid black;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
padding-left: 50px;
}

div.clear {
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! But if i try this in JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/u6qtpye7/ i don't get a horizontal tree in chrome, because every node is in a new row.